# How to see Entity Framework generated SQL code using ASP.NET Core, dotnet cli and Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-cli

How to see Entity Framework generated SQL code using ASP.NET Core, dotnet cli and Visual Studio Code?

In terminal, I run `dotnet watch run`. When you call a Web API, the terminal window should show the EF generated SQL code. But I cannot see it.

Comment: How are you running the web api (run or debug mode), have you enabled verbose logging/debuging?

Comment: In the Web API, did you access the `DbContext` which will query from the database? To check the SQL query in terminal windows, you need to access the DbContext to query object like  `   public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            var result = _context.ApplicationUser.ToList();          
            return View();
        } `